# Output type="number" with flask-wtforms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

```
from flask.ext.wtf.html5 import NumberInput

class Form(Form):
    value = NumberInput( [Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Next')
```

---

```
{{ form.value }}
```

---

The code above will output this:

```
<wtforms.widgets.html5.NumberInput object at 0x3c94a50>
```

Well, what i am expecting is:

```
<input type="number">
```

Basically, the question is how can I render an `input type="number"` with wtforms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your `value` should be a field, not a widget.

```
value = IntegerField(widget=NumberInput())
```

WTForms fields generate html on call, so try

```
{{ form.value() }}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.    `{{ form.value() }}
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: I don't know if it is in the docs, I haven't read it. I have read the source code though, and it was pretty easy to follow.